# Issues transferring data from one view to the next

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, data-structures

I'm building an iPhone app, and am just wondering what's the best way to "send" data from one view to another? For example, if I have a UITableView full of information (table.data), and when pressed I show a "detail view" and want to give the user the option to open up a URL shown in the "detail view" in an in-app web browser, how do I "push" the URL into the browser view?

Thanks.

Comment: Just create another UIViewController that contains UIWebView and push it on the screen. Lookling at UINavigationController might be useful for you.

Comment: Yeah it's the actual code that's my problem. I already have the navigation controller, but what do I use to "push the *NSURL to the Web VIew? I.E. How do I declare it in the UIWebView?

Comment: You don't declare it IN the UIWebView, you declare it in the UIViewController containing the UIWebView. Declaring properties is very basic stuff and really something you should be able to find a tutorial about somewhere on the WWW

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease]
```

Comment: Using that, what would you have as the viewDidLoad code? I currently have: 
 NSString *urlAddress = [incident link];
 
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 
 [webView loadRequest:requestObj];